# How to detect file leak and the corresponding code in Solaris?

Tags: c++, unix, solaris

How to detect file leak and the corresponding stack in Solaris? I see the information was well reported by valgrind on Linux.  Please let me know if we have any tools on Solaris also?

Comment: File leak is a scenario where you open sockets or file descriptors and don't close it. The same code may be called many a times resulting in a file leak.

Comment: The term is **Resource Leak**

Comment: Use RAII properly and your resource leaks will almost certainly resolve themselves...

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can use [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) to log all file **open** and **close** calls. Then you can analyse the log on Resource Leak - the number of **open** calls should match the number of **close** calls. If this is not true then you have a leak. On Solaris there is a similar tool - [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace).

Comment: `dtrace` isn't particularly close to `strace`; in fact, the Solaris _equivalent_ to `strace` is `truss` (up to the point of many command line options for the two doing the same thing). Linux `dtrace`-inspired functionality would be SystemTap, `stap` & friends.

Comment: You would also need to do some bookkeeping to get some useful information about the leak - e.g. the stack trace (or at least source code location)  where the leaked file descriptor was opened(). Of course, you would also need to cover `dup()` etc. for that. Thus, strace or truss would not be sufficient, since you can't get stack traces/location information with them.

Answer (score 2):

You can, in Solaris, look at currently open filedescriptors of a process by simply using the `pfiles` command. If you want to track files being opened/closed, `truss` (the Solaris equivalent to `strace`) comes to mind, with a filter for file-related syscalls (`truss -e open,close` but there are others that create filedescriptors).

If you find that the `pfiles` output grows, first identify whether what you're leaking are ordinary files or things like sockets / pipes. If it's leaking ordinary files, then a `dtrace` script can be used; the following is a base for own experiments, I currently don't have a Solaris system at hand to try it out and refine it. See below.

```
#!/usr/bin/dtrace -s

syscall::open:entry { self->t = ustack(); }
syscall::open:return /arg0 >= 0/ { trackedfds[arg0] = self->t; }
syscall::open:return { self->t = 0; }

syscall::close:entry { self->t = arg0; }
syscall::close:return /arg0 >= 0/ { trackedfds[self->t] = 0; }
syscall::close:return { self->t = 0; }

END { printa(trackedfds); }
```

This builds an associative array indexed by filedescriptor number whose contents are the userside stacktrace at the time of the `open()` system call. On successful close, the entry for the given filedescriptor number is discarded, and when the program exits (or the script is stopped) the remaining contents of said associative array are printed - if anything's left, that'd be a candidate for leaks.

Note that the `END {}` probe might not be the correct place for this; `proc::exit` or something of the like may be required. It depends on when exactly this triggers, before or after the cleanup done at program teardown (exiting / killing a program closes all its filedescriptors, which would erase the `trackedfds[]` array). That's why I've said above this is a starting point, I can't check without a Solaris system.

Comment: There are 2 issues with that snippet: 1) associative arrays (unlike aggregations) can't be printed in dtrace - they are not supported by printing statements and you can't iterate over them because there aren't any loop statements 2) utrace() is not allowed on the right hand side like this. It is fine as aggregation key, and standalone - but not as an expression.